# How can I set "secure_file_privilege" with MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, configuration

How to

```
 SET @@global.secure_file_priv=""
```

on Mac Mojave using MySQL Workbench to use `Load_file` options?

I coudn't find it in `my.cnf`.

Answer (score 0):

sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist;

edit the file add --secure-file-priv=/var/../../ still in locked state

restart the server again 
and it will work perfectly fine.

query @secure_file_priv you will get the directory you edited .Hope that helps.